# How to read javascript values from python with PyV8

Tags: javascript, python, api, v8

I've implemented PyV8 into Python. I have an example javascript file that looks like this:

### main-js.js:

```
var numOne = 1+2;
var numTwo = 3+1;
var numThree = 5;
```

How do I read each variable into Python with PyV8? So far I've opened and read the file with this:
ctxt.eval(open("main-js.js").read()). But i don't know how to grab each variable from the file. This is hard to find due to the lack of documentation with pyv8

Answer (score 3):

The `JSContext` object has a `locals` attribute which is a dictionary of the context's local variables. So, you want `ctxt.locals["numOne"]` and so on.

Another way to do it: `eval()` has a return value, which is the value of the last statement evaluated. So you could also execute a JavaScript statement that evaluates the variables you're interested in. In this case you could just create a JavaScript array of them, which you can then unpack into the Python variables you want. You could do this by appending the statement to the code you read from the file, or just execute a separate `eval()` for it:

```
with PyV8.JSContext() as ctxt:
    with open("main-js.js") as jsfile:
        ctxt.eval(jsfile.read())
    numOne, numTwo, numThree = ctxt.eval("[numOne, numTwo, numThree]")
```

Comment: Very quick one more. What if I have a function in my javascript that returns a value. For instance:
function getStr(){
   return "hello"
}
How would I call the function and pull the return value with pyv8

Comment: NEVERMIND. I figured it out :) Thanks a bunch